# Get specific cell value from Playwright typescript

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-typescript

I have a table with n columns and rows. Would like to fetch "Column X" value whose "Name" is "Ram" through playwright
[image: Example Table]

I have tried through Iteration but didnt work (All my headers are in table1 and body content in table2)

```
let columns = await this.page.locator("//th[@role='columnheader']").count();
for (var i = 0; i < await columns; i++) {
        //getting the column header
        let val = await this.page.locator("//th[@role='columnheader']//span[contains(@class,'mat-tooltip-trigger')]").nth(i).innerText()

    //When column header equal to expected header, fetching the cell value of row-1
    if (val == value) {
      return await this.page.locator("//table//tbody//tr[1]//td").nth(i);
      break
    }``
```

Comment: It depends on if the th row is in a thead or in the tbody. Your xpath in the td locator is definitely wrong

Comment: All my headers are in table1 and body is in table2

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the page and/or relevant markup. There's no way to tell what's going on based on the screenshot. Generally, there's no need for xpaths in Playwright.

Answer (score 0):

You can get and assert the specific cell value in this way.

const tableSelector = 'table#yourTableID'; **// provide CSS selector of your table**

**// Replace with the row and column indices you want (both are 0-based).**

const rowIndex = 2;
const columnIndex = 1;

**// Locate the table and cell using Playwright functions.**

const table = await page.$(tableSelector);

const cell = await table.$(`tr:nth-child(${rowIndex}) td:nth-child(${columnIndex})`);

**// Assert that the cell exists.**

await expect(cell).not.toBeNull();

**// Extract and assert the cell content.**

const cellValue = await cell.textContent();
await expect(cellValue).toBe('Expected Cell Value');

Comment: Yes but they don't know those values up front. Also nth-child is 1-based

Answer (score 0):

We can find the specific row based on name text as "Ram" and as column number will be static we can just pass the actual column number :

```
await this.page.locator('//table//tbody//tr[contains(.,"Ram")]//td').nth(staticColNum)
```